# Returning a list of elements occurring in both lists - SML

Tags: list, sml

)I am just starting with SML and have been trying to write a function that takes two lists, L1 and L2, and returns a list of elements that occur in both. This is what I have so far:

```
fun exists x nil = false | exists x (h::t) = (x = h) orelse (exists x t);

    fun listAnd L1 nil = nil
     | listAnd nil L2 = nil
     | listAnd L1 L2 = if exists(hd(L1) L2) = true then hd(L1)::(listAnd(tl(L1) L2)) else listAnd(tl(L1) L2);
```

I am not really sure where is the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `exists` is a function taking two arguments, your mistake is to put extra parentheses around both arguments. For example, `exists(hd(L1) L2)` should corrected as `exists (hd L1) L2`.

I have a few suggestions:

- removing redundant `= true`
- using `[]` for empty list and wildcard `_` for unused values
- using pattern matching on `L1` instead of `hd` and `tl`

Now this is the corrected function:

```
fun listAnd _ [] = []
  | listAnd [] _ = []
  | listAnd (x::xs) ys = if exists x ys 
                         then x::(listAnd xs ys) 
                         else listAnd xs ys
```